# materialize input label error using jquery validation remote message error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, materialize

I have a `materialize form` where I want to add an `rest api call` to validate if the e-mail already exist on `database`. What I need is to put the "E-mail not available" message on the `label` "E-mail" that I have on the form, just like "Type your e-mail" and "Type an valid e-mail" already appears.

This is the `jquery code`:

```
$("#formSignup").validate({
  rules : {
       email:{
               required:true,
               email: true,
               remote: {
               url: '/validateemail/me@me.com',  
                      type: 'GET',  
                      success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {  
                          console.log(data);  
                      },  
                      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                          console.log('error in operation');  
                      } 
                }
       },
  messages:{
        email:{
               required: "Type your e-mail",
               email: "Type an valid e-mail",
               remote: "E-mail not available"
        }
  },
```

This is the `materialize` code:

```
<div class="row">
  <form class="col s12" id="formSignup">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" name="email" required aria-required="true">
        <label class="defaultlabel" for="email">Email *</label>              
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I already tried to put `return true;` and `return false;` inside the `if-else` respectively in the `jquery`, but neither worked

Comment: And what about the server-side code at `/validateemail/me@me.com`?  What's going on with that?

Comment: You don't even show us where you put the `if/else` you're talking about.  Please refer to the documentation examples as well as the link for duplicate for how to properly implement the `remote` rule.